# What are the risk in posting Ionic app in Apple app store?

Tags: ionic-framework, app-store

I'm planning on using an Ionic approach with react for a corporate application. The problem is I'm worried about apple blocking the publication in the app store as it's not a native application.

Anyone has driven this road?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your application conforms to all requirements it will be fine.

In particular be aware of https://ionicframework.com/blog/understanding-itms-90809-uiwebview-api-deprecation/

and
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/wkwebview/